# How to initialize an interface from API response using TypeScript and React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to render an API response on a React + TypeScript view component. Here are the interfaces that are used to represent the API response (in this case stocks) and API error:

```
export interface IStocks {
    [key: string]: string;
}

export interface IErrors {
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

Here is a function that gets the stocks from some API, there are compile time errors which I need help for:

```
private async getStocks(): Promise<IStocks> {
    /*
      Generic type 'Promise<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)

      Ok, but how do I make this function know about IErrors and IStocks types? What is the correct way?

       */


    try {
        let response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/stocks', {
            method: "get",
            headers: new Headers({
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Accept: "application/json"
            })
        });
        return (IStocks) response;

        /*
         'IStocks' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)


         I wanted to map the response to 'IStocks' interface simply, my way is incorrect but then how do I do it

         */

    } catch (ex) {
        return (IErrors) ex;
        /*
        'IErrors' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)

         I wanted to map the response to 'IErrors' interface simply, my way is incorrect but then how do I do it

        */
    }

    return null;

}
```

Basically, I want to map the API error object `ex` to the `IErrors` interface for type checking and the API response object to the `IStocks` interface.

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean the function returns a promise of IStocks **or** IErrors? Maybe look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe Okey, I wanted to make sure that the stocks are in a particular format. Let's forget about errors for now. So how will I do it then?

Comment: What do you mean "make sure"? TypeScript doesn't exist at runtime, it can't do any checking, casting or conversion.

Comment: @jonrsharpe "TS doesn't exist in runtime" so I should use class you mean? I remember reading class getting compiled to js AFAIK

Comment: I'd strongly recommend reading up on the basics of the language you're trying to use. You seem to be using Java type casting, which TS doesn't do. The interfaces *describe* what you're expecting in the response, and as they only use basic JSON types they don't need any conversion.

Answer (score 3):

For such functionality I would recommend a library like [axios](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwjT96Dc6fziAhXHYlAKHUUIAowQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Faxios%2Faxios&usg=AOvVaw266wVW3XPRY46nOw2ULXdh).

If for whatever reason you can't use libraries like this, I would make a generic wrapper for the fetch method:

```
export const typedFetch = <T>(
  request: RequestInfo,
  requestInit?: RequestInit
): Promise<T> => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    fetch(request, requestInit)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(body => {
        resolve(body);
      });
  });
};

// Usage:
const data = await typedFetch<IStocks[]>(
  "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/stocks",
  {
    method: "get",
    headers: new Headers({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json"
    })
  }
);
```

You should probably change how your API handles errors as well, you can't have two separate models for your API response.

You should return all your data in a wrapped response that contains your data as well as other info like potential errors, messages, status codes, etc.

The JSON returned by your API could look like this:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "errors": [],
    "data": [
        /* Stocks */
    ]
}

{
    "status": 500,
    "errors": [
        /* ERRORS */
    ],
    "data": []
}
```

Then you would deserialize your data using a generic model on your client side:

```
interface IApiResponse<T> {
    status: number;
    errors: IErrors[];
    data: T;
}

const data = await typedFetch<IApiResponse<IStocks[]>>("url", ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Ok, but how do I make this function know about IErrors and IStocks types? What is the correct way?

Promise has a single generic type: the type of the successful response. If you have an error, its type is `any`, and it's up to you to know what the error actually is.

`return (IStocks) response;`

That's Java, not TypeScript. In TypeScript, the syntax is

```
return response as IStocks;
```

Note however that fetch returns a `Promise<Response>`. A Response contains more that the body of the response. Read the documentation and/or use your IDE to see what properties and methods exist in Response, and how to properly extract the JSON body from the response.

Comment: `Response` can be in any format and I'm getting this now:  `Conversion of type 'Response' to type 'IStocks' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Index signature is missing in type 'Response'.ts(2352)`

Comment: Read the end of my answer. I'm just fixing your syntax error to explain that your type cast syntax is not correct. But there is more: you need to extract the JSON body from the response. The documentation and the IDE are your friends